# Is there any way to perform a batched request in Asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have an API built using ASP.Net Core, and we would like to consolidate multiple requests into one HTTP requests for performance reasons.

In previous versions of asp.net you could allow for batch requests via the [DefaultHttpBatchHandler](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/855284/How-to-Avoid-API-Requests-On-Your-Page).

Unfortunately, no such thing seems to exist in Asp.net Core.

Is anyone aware of any way to do HTTP batches in core?

Comment: The source code for the batch handler is available on Github in class [DefaultHttpBatchHandler](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Batch/DefaultHttpBatchHandler.cs) : [HttpBatchHandler](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Batch/HttpBatchHandler.cs) { ... }. check how it was implemented in handlers and create a custom middleware to perform the same functionality. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: There are enough changes between Asp.net and Asp.net core that made that non-trivial to port.  Since it's been a good 6 months since I originally asked this question I can't remember what parts were not easy to port, I just remember I saw that code and couldn't use it without rewriting it all.

Answer (score 5):

After doing my research on the matter, this seems fairly simple to implement. However, I think it should be supported by the official asp.net core team.

To me it seems like it requires a middleware creating multiple `RouteContext` according to the inputted text, and just invoking their Handlers - and modifying their response. it might be a little bit more difficult, because it would require support for multiple responses for an `HttpContext` (as far as I know it seems like it will be shared across Controllers).

Anyway, There is an open [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/262) in the official repository that I have risen from the dead, hoping it will move things along. I might work on an implementation in the future if there are no changes soon.

#### Update

Seems like the asp.net team responded to the request, and created a new [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/issues/246) that is set to 2.0 milestone, so I am guessing this feature will be available during asp.net 2.0 release.

Comment: We ended up implementing our own batch middleware.  We ended up doing some non-conventional things anyway (such as inner requests in the batch performing their operations via parallel http calls to better load balance the work).  It also made it much easier because trying to do it inline while controlling and resetting the HTTP context in asp.net core is not very easy to do and gave way too many edge cases.

Comment: are we like focussing on building an Api gateway kind of thing that propagates the incoming request to multiple endpoints and aggregates the result back to the calling app

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand? Do you mean 1 exposed endpoint that makes multiple calls?

Can you not have 1 API action that just creates multiple Tasks (that will run in parallel), waits for them all to complete then return all response data (combined or separated as required)?

Comment: Not really, because assuming you are using MVC, you would need to be able to call any controller action from that endpoint. This would definitely require some sort of middleware. You don't have that data in a controller endpoint.

Comment: You could of course make a single endpoint that does a bunch of actions, but that would require you to write unnecessary exta code that breaks your entire architecture.

Comment: Sure, I assume code will need to be written somewhere or accessible from somewhere, so guess I don't understand your problem completely.

Comment: I added a bounty to see if anyone implemented such middleware, or knows how exactly to do it, and save me some work. I am currently researching the matter, seems like no official middleware has been implemented, and I am working through the `aspnet/router` code to see how difficult it would be to implement it myself.

Comment: [That](http://www.michalbialecki.com/2018/04/19/how-to-send-many-requests-in-parallel-in-asp-net-core/) could be smth similar that you said about