# Batch Processing POST with WebApi Net CORE 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

We have a current standard Web Api running on `Net 5.0` where we want to add the ability to batch process
requests.

I have found `System.Web.Http.Batch` library and have looked to implement the `api/batch` endpoint.

I have found an example of mapping as follows;

```
httpServer.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(routeName: "batch", routeTemplate: "api/batch", batchHandler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(httpServer));
```

On my `NET 5.0` api I configure the routes in `startup.cs` using;

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Is there a way for configuring this through the endpoints mapping? As I cannot access the `MapHttpBatchRoute` method?

Can anyone advise how I should implement this please?

Comment: Check [this tutorial to create a Batch Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/shopping-content/code-example-create-batch-request) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027085/is-there-any-way-to-perform-a-batched-request-in-asp-net-core)